# Inserting rows to the top of a UITableView causes the rows to shift down resulting in bad animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've an app that behaves like a typical messaging app.

Let's say the user has 100 messages and my page size is 20. When the user lands on the page I show the last page (messages from 80 - 100).

As the user scrolls up slowly I fetch the previous page (60 - 80) when `willDisplay`'s indexPath becomes `indexPath.row = 0 && indexPath.section = 0`. I build the dataSource array and call `insertRows:at:with:`. The issue i'm running into is that when I insert the rows, it starts from `indexPath.row = 0 && indexPath.section = 0` which causes it to trigger the prefetching of previous page resulting in premature pre-fetching of rest of the pages. I can have a flag to avoid this but it still pushes down the rest of the cells causing it to loose the scrolling position and then goes back resulting in a flashing animation.

I use `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to calculate the cell height.

I've experimented with calls to `scrollToRow(at:at:animated)` but it still pushes down when `insertRows:` is called.

I know this is theoretically possible because apps like Whatsapp and iMessage have this behavior (assuming they use a tableView) and they work well.

Here's a gist of what i have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !insertingRows && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        loadData()
    }
}

private func loadData() {
    dataSource.load({ [weak self] (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        let newMessagesCount = 20 // testing
        var indices = [IndexPath]()
        for index in stride(from: 0, to: newMessagesCount, by: 1) {
            indices.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            strongSelf.insertingRows = true
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            strongSelf.tableView.insertRows(at: indices, with: .none)
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            strongSelf.insertingRows = false
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the tableView's insert rows functionality, you could just add the elements to the datasource.  You could then replace the code in your DispatchQueue.main.async function with the code below.

```
let oldContentHeight: CGFloat = tableView.contentSize.height
let oldOffsetY: CGFloat = tableView.contentOffset.y
tableView.reloadData()
let newContentHeight: CGFloat = tableView.contentSize.height
tableView.contentOffset.y = oldOffsetY + (newContentHeight - oldContentHeight)
```

See this gist I found for more info:
https://gist.github.com/WorldDownTown/9ed681148e9224f7157c9e8620ce46b8